# calculating upper bound on normalized weighted levenshtein distance

Tags: c++, algorithm, strings, edit-distance

### Current implementation

I am using a normalized weighted Levenshtein distance for two utf32 strings with the following costs (insertion: 1, deletion: 1, replacement: 2). The normalization is performed in the following way:

```cpp
1 - distance / (s1.size() + s2.size())
```

In cases where I am only interested in results above a certain threshold, I use faster string metrics to calculate a upper bound on this normalized Levenshtein distance.
I use the following logic to perform the calculation:

- calculate ratio based on string lengths -> exit early
- remove common prefix and suffix of the two strings
- count uncommon characters between the two trimmed strings -> exit early
- calculate the weighted levenshtein distance between the two trimmed strings

To count uncommon characters between the two strings I use the following two implementations:
This first implementation is used, when I know, that all characters in one of the strings are close together. E.g. when there are only ASCII characters.

```cpp
template <size_t MaxChar, size_t MinChar = 0, typename CharT1, typename CharT2>
std::size_t count_uncommon_chars(const std::basic_string<CharT1>& s1, const std::basic_string<CharT2>& s2)
{
  std::array<signed int, MaxChar - MinChar> char_freq{};
  for (const auto& ch : s1) {
    ++char_freq[ch - MinChar];
  }

  std::size_t count = 0;

  for (const auto& ch : s2) {
    if (ch > MaxChar + MinChar || ch < MinChar) {
      count += 1;
    } else {
      --char_freq[ch - MinChar];
    }
  }

  for (const auto& freq : char_freq) {
    count += std::abs(freq);
  }

  return count;
}
```

Since the first implementation gets really unefficient when the characters are not all close to each other, this second implementation is used for all other strings.

```cpp
template <typename CharT1, typename CharT2>
std::size_t count_uncommon_chars(std::basic_string<CharT1> s1, std::basic_string<CharT2> s2)
{
  if (s1.empty()) {
    return s2.size();
  }
  if (s2.empty()) {
    return s1.size();
  }

  std::sort(s1.begin(), s1.end());
  std::sort(s2.begin(), s2.end());

  std::size_t count = 0;
  std::size_t pos_s1 = 0;
  std::size_t pos_s2 = 0;

  while (pos_s1 < s1.size() && pos_s2 < s2.size()) {
    if (s1[pos_s1] == s2[pos_s2]) {
      ++pos_s1;
      ++pos_s2;
    } else if (s1[pos_s1] < s2[pos_s2]) {
      ++count;
      ++pos_s1;
    } else {
      ++count;
      ++pos_s2;
    }
  }
  if (pos_s1 == s1.size()) {
    return count + s2.size() - pos_s2;
  }
  return count + s1.size() - pos_s1;
}
```

An alternative for the second implementation I considered is:

```cpp
template <typename CharT1, typename CharT2>
std::size_t count_uncommon_chars(const std::basic_string<CharT1>& s1, const std::basic_string<CharT2>& s2)
{
  std::array<signed int, 256> char_freq{};
  for (const auto& ch : s1) {
    ++char_freq[ch % 256];
  }

  for (const auto& ch : s2) {
    --char_freq[ch % 256];
  }

  std::size_t count = 0;
  for (const auto& freq : char_freq) {
    count += std::abs(freq);
  }

  return count;
}
```

This alternative is faster, but considers multiple characters as similar (allows exiting early in fewer cases)

### Additional information on the usage

In most cases I compare one string to multiple strings, to find e.g. the best match. So it would be useful when parts of the algorithm can be precalculated when only one string is known, to reduce duplicated work. The current implementations could be changed, so:

- implementation 1 and the alternative implementation can create the `char_freq` array ahead of time (without knowing which type of characters the second string holds)
- implementation 2 can sort one of the string ahead of time

The most common ranges of characters are:

- 0 - 0x7F (ASCII character)
- 0 - 0xFF (utf32 character stored in 8 bit)
- 0 - 0xFFFF (utf32 character stored in 16 bit)
- 0 - 0x10FFFF (limit of utf32)

The strings are often preprocessed before they are compared. The preprocessor performs the following changes:

- non alphanumeric characters are replaced with a whitespace (whitespaces are excluded from this)
- characters are changed to lowercase

### Question

Is there a more efficient implementation for letters that are far apart without giving up a large part of the precision as in the alternative implementation?

Comment: Good first question!  Welcome to Code Review.